# obfs4proxy error

Tags: configuration

Ubuntu 20.4 - Digital Ocean Droplet Tor Bridge Relay

```
[WARN] Pluggable Transport process terminated with status code 256
```

Anyone have a suggestion for the solution of this tor bridge puzzle?
As a relay (minus bridge settings) the settings below has been up and running for almost two months.

torrc

```
SocksPort 0
RunAsDaemon 1
ORPort xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:7669
BridgeRelay 1
BridgeRecordUsageByCountry 1
ServerTransportPlugin obfs4 exec /user/bin/obfs4proxy
ServerTransportListenAddr obfs4 0.0.0.0:1111
ExtORPort auto
Nickname me
ContactInfo me@mail.com 
Log notice file /var/log/tor/notices.log
Log Debug file /var/log/tor/debug.log
ExitPolicy reject *:*
RelayBandwidthRate 
RelayBandwidthBurst 
DisableDebuggerAttachment 0
ControlPort 9051
CookieAuthentication 1
```

Thank you for your help! > Adriann

Comment: Maybe try `/usr/bin/obfs4proxy` instead of `/user/bin/obfs4proxy`

Comment: In other words, a typo! I asked the same question on the tor list and none of them caught it either. So I don't feel so bad.  :-) Thank you Steve